# What does the Function of LOG() do?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a **BTS** C++ code, i faced a command that i don't know its functionality, i wish anyone here could help me

```
LOG(INFO) << *cmsrq;
```

Here what is the function of **LOG**. it's not a logarithmic function.

Comment: Probably some sort of logging function (or perhaps macro, since it's all uppercase? Would be a bit out-of-place in C++ code). Seems to return a logging output stream of level INFO.

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You have the code, not us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very probably a MACRO that gives you back an object which logs (to console or file) what you pass it through the `<<` operator.

Much like [qDebug()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html).

The value "INFO" you see in there indicates that you want to output the `*cmsrq` value to the *information* log level.

I can imagine some macro definition like that:

```
#define LOG( X )  Logging::logger( X )
```

Where `logger()` is a static function returning a reference of the logging engine class, initialized with the correct log level.

Answer (score 2):

From the context, the line of code:

```
LOG(INFO) << *cmsrq;
```

writes an entry to a [log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_logging).

Logs are typically used to record the activities of a computer system. One purpose of keeping such logs is troubleshooting malfunctions.

In the code that you show, the function (or macro) `LOG()` returns an output stream that is used to log messages associated with the given logging level (`INFO` probably stands for "informational messages").

Comment: It actually doesn't look like it does the actual logging, it just returns an `OStream`...